# Index was outside the bounds of the array powershell

Tags: powershell

I want multiple data fetching from excel sheet. I am getting error is   Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
$Data = Read-Host "Enter the count of Datastore"
$ds = "-sm-"
$Range1 = $Worksheetx1.Range("B1","B1048570")
$Search1 = $Range1.find($ds)
$r = $Search1.row

for ($i=1; $i -le $Data; $i++)
    {
    $Datastore = @()
    $Datastore[$i] = $Worksheetx1.Cells.Item($r, 2).Value2
    $r = $r+1
    }

$Total_Datastore = $Datastore1 + $Datastore2 + $Datastore3 + $Datastore4

$Total_Datastore
```

Comment: normally, PoSh provides far more info in an error message. so ... what is the FULL error message you are getting? - please put that info into your Original Post, not into the comments.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, you're redefining `$Datastore` with every loop iteration ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in this code:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le $Data; $i++)
{
    $Datastore = @()
    $Datastore[$i] = $Worksheetx1.Cells.Item($r, 2).Value2
    $r = $r+1
}
```

You're creating an empty array `$Datastore = @()`, and try to store data in the second index (`$i=1`, array index starts at zero, therefore index two). This causes an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Also `$Total_Datastore = $Datastore1 + $Datastore2 + $Datastore3 + $Datastore4` doesn't make sense, since `$Datastore1` (2,3 and 4) aren't defined anywhere.

Try:

```
 # Only integers are allowed
 $Data = [int] (Read-Host "Enter the count of Datastore")
 $ds = "-sm-"
 $Range1 = $Worksheetx1.Range("B1","B1048570")
 $Search1 = $Range1.find($ds)
 $r = $Search1.row

 $Datastore = @()
 for ($i=1; $i -le $Data; $i++) {
     # Todo: Check if $r is in a valid range or not !!!
     $Datastore += $Worksheetx1.Cells.Item($r, 2).Value2
     $r = $r+1
 }

 $Datastore
```

Comment: @Ayyappa, thx. Please mark the answer as correct one -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I am using this site first time. Please let me know the where to accept